# How do I make a path a variable and then move that file

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to create a batch file that searches for .pst files and then moves it those files to a specific location. So far this is what I have. Please help.

```
cd \   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /r %%i in (*.pst) do (   
::echo %%~i

set MyPath=%i%   
move "%MyPath%" "C:\users\zack.vigrass\desktop\"
)

endlocal

PAUSE
```

edit: I didn't realize I wasn't asking a question. I was mostly asking Why does it returned a blank file instead of the intended .pst file.

Comment: why not `move %%i` directly ? And I guess `%i%` is just a typo here in your example ? If all of this does not apply: please state your specific problem, at present you are only stating facts and not asking a question.

Comment: another victim of the famous [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)... (and of course that typo, that @Marged noted)

Comment: set "MyPath=%%i" (with qoutes around and the `%` corrected), so any trailing spaces will no longer become part of the `MyPath` value...

Comment: Careful using `:: Comment` in blocks of code, safer to use `rem comment` there.

Answer (score 2):

```
set MyPath=%i%
```

will **not** set `mypath` to the contents of the metavariable controlling the `for` loop (`%%i`, but will set it to the contents of `i` which is an ordinary environment variable, most likely undefined and hence *nothing*.

Extra problem : there are trailing spaces on the line which will be **included** in the value assigned.

Hence `mypath` will acquire a value of *(a few spaces)*

```
move "%MyPath%" "C:\users\zack.vigrass\desktop\"
```

Unfortunately, batch replaces the value of any `%var%` within a block (a series of parenthesised statements) literally with the value of that variable at the time the `for` (in this instance) is encountered.

Since when the `for` is encountered, `mypath` is undefined, then the result will be

```
move "" "C:\users\zack.vigrass\desktop\"
```

There appears to be no reason in this instance to transfer the value to `mypath`.

```
move "%%i" "C:\users\zack.vigrass\desktop\"
```

should work for you.

Comment: Thank you this seemed to fix my issues. I appreciate the help.